# how do I override php://input when doing unit tests

Tags: php, unit-testing, zend-framework, phpunit

I'm trying to write a unit test for a controller using Zend and PHPUnit

In the code I get data from php://input

```
$req = new Zend_Controller_Request_Http();
$data = $req->getRawBody();
```

My code works fine when I test the real application, but unless I can supply data as a raw http post, $data will always be blank.  The getRawBody() method basically calls file_get_contents('php://input'), but how do I override this in order to supply the test data to my application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Provided the `$req->getRawBody()` is, as you say, the same as `file_get_contents('php://input')`...

```
$test = true; /* Set to TRUE when using Unit Tests */

$req = new Zend_Controller_Request_Http();
if( $test )
  $data = file_get_contents( 'testfile.txt' );
else
  $data = $req->getRawBody();
```

Not a perfect solution, but similar to what I have used in the past when designing scripts to handle piped emails with great success.

Comment: Yeap, not a perfect solution, but how I've decided to implement it too.  Thanks.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend this solution -- using `if` statements to perform different code in unit tests versus production. You ideally want your code to execute the same logical statements in both worlds. See @MitMaro's solution below which uses a configurable input path.

Answer (score 11):

I had the same problem and the way I fixed it was to have the `'php://input'` string as a variable that is settable at run time. I know this does not really apply directly to this question as it would require modifying the Zend Framework. But all the same it may be helpful to someone.

For example:

```
<?php
class Foo {

    public function read() {
        return file_get_contents('php://input');
    } 
}
```

would become

```
<?php
class Foo {

    public $_fileIn = 'php://input';

    public function read() {
        return file_get_contents($this->_fileIn);
    }

}
```

Then in my unit test I can do:

```
<?php
$obj = new Foo();
$obj->_fileIn = 'my_input_data.dat';
assertTrue('foo=bar', $obj->read());
```

Comment: you also could have a protected property and change it to public using reflection in the tests. So for production your code is a little cleaner. (Assuming php 5.3)

Answer (score 7):

You could try mocking the object in your unit tests.  Something like this:

```
$req = $this->getMock('Zend_Controller_Request_Http', array('getRawBody'));
$req->method('getRawBody')
    ->will($this->returnValue('raw_post_data_to_return'));
```

Comment: so this would work if I was passing Zend_Controller_Request_Http object into the code I was testing, unfortunately the controller handles all this under the hood.  So I think the only way to do it is to change my application to test for the environment I'm in and handle the special case.

Answer (score 0):

[Zend_Controller_Request_HttpTestCase](http://framework.zend.com/apidoc/1.7/Zend_Controller/Request/Zend_Controller_Request_HttpTestCase.html) contains methods for setting and getting various http request/responses.

For example:

    `$req = new Zend_Controller_Request_HttpTestCase;
    $req->setCookie('cookie', 'TRUE');
    $test = $this->controller->cookieAction($req);
    $this->assertSame($test, TRUE);`